# Windows 10 Pro expires soon

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

I have a legitimate copy of windows 10 volume licensed through my company.  I'm also part of the windows insider program.  Lately I'm getting a message that my copy of windows will expire on 7/15/2016... and I've updated to the very latest insider build (14383.rs1_release.160701-1839).

When I go to the activation tab in settings, there are no error messages and no button to change my product key.  Everything looks fine.  But on every start I still get that warning popping up.

Anyone experience something similar or know how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote the following message from Microsoft:

> **Known issues for PC**:
>   If you are seeing a notification pop-up once a day that started on 7/1 saying that your Windows evaluation copy expires on 7/15/2016, don’t worry – this is a superfluous dialog and your OS won’t expire.  The dialog will also go away soon.

Source: [Miscrosoft Q&A](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/expiration-dates-for-windows-10-insider-preview/b52753c5-2329-4e83-8e0e-b27b715bdfba).

PS: I personally don't recommend anyone to use the Windows Insider version for a productive working machine. The OS is under development -- not mature, and you may experience a lot of weird things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to file explore -> right click on "This PC" -> properties. New window will appear with computer info. Scroll to bottom and see if it says "Windows is activated". If it is not, try to enter in your product key again. If there is no option in that window to enter a product key then open up a command prompt. Bottom left of desktop search for "cmd" without quotes. A black box should appear after you run the program. in the command prompt type "slui 3" without quotes and hit Enter. This will bring up another window that will let you enter your product key.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this bug is [fixed in Build 14385](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/07/09/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14385-for-pc-and-mobile/)

> **Improvements and fixes for PC**
>
> - You should no longer see a notification pop-up once a day saying that your Windows evaluation copy expires on 7/15/2016. I know this
>     has caused a lot of you some angst so thank you for being patient.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on Start and select Command Prompt (Admin) then click Yes when the User account control appears what result do you get if you type slmgr.vbs /xpr then press Enter key?

If the message shows "**The machine is permanently activated**". It means you don't worry about your activation code. I not you have to set key original Key.